# How can I insert links into swf files using PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to insert links into a swf banner(on all its surface) automatically using php. I am almost sure I saw this feature in OpenAds...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but this can't be done apart from having a click-handler in the SWF that takes the location target of the click as a parameter, in which case the parameter is given to the Flash-file on html-level.

Eg

```
<object>
    <param name="movie" value="YOURFLASH.swf" />
    <param name="flashVars" value="clickTag=http%3A//www.example.com/&amp;clickTAG=http%3A//www.example.com/&amp;clicktag=http%3A//www.example.com/&amp;clickTag2=http%3A//www.example.com/" />
    <embed src="YOURFLASH.swf" flashvars="clickTag=http%3A//www.example.com/&amp;clickTAG=http%3A//www.example.com/&amp;clicktag=http%3A//www.example.com/&amp;clickTag2=http%3A//www.example.com/"></embed>
</object>
```

The parameter name clicktag (in different case-variants) is a common parameter name for setting a click-handler in banners.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to place a div over a flash clip in html and put your links there. This requires very careful positioning and may look weird.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to the flash source you could load the links from a resource generated with PHP (or any server side tech) from within the flash.

Then your links are generated as xml/json/html and the flash displays them.

google `flash loading data` for a bunch of different tutorials and articles.